# Open/closed, bounded, compact sets of sequences

Tags: functional-analysis, compactness

Given the sets 
$$E := \{x = (x_n)_n ∈ \ell^1 | n\in N \Rightarrow 0 < x_n < 1/n\}$$ 
$$K := \{x = (x_n)_n ∈ \ell^1
|n\in N \Rightarrow 0 ≤ x_n ≤ 1/n\}$$
I have to prove or disprove that $E$ is open, bounded, compact in $(\ell^1,\|.\|_1)$ and that $K$ is closed, bounded, compact.

Comment: ok, what have you tried?

Comment: I didn't write it just because I'm not familiar with MathJax (neither with writing proves in english . . .) and it would have taken ages. I found an accumulation point for E that doesn't belong to E so I know it's not closed, but this doesn't imply that it's open and I can't prove that. Meanwhile I managed to prove they're both not bounded so not compact but I'm not sure.

Comment: You need to make some attempts. There is no recipe. For the first one, try $x_k = ({1 \over k},0,0,...)$. Are the $x_k \in E$? Does $x_k$ converge? Is the limit in $E$?

Comment: @copper.hat it's not in E because it's not always <1/n, it converges to $0$ and the limit is not in E. I don't understand . . .

Comment: OK, try modifying the example a tiny bit to get it in $E$. You need to do a little work here!

Comment: @copper.hat it's exactly what I used to prove that E is not closed and exactly the reason why I wrote the question here, I just said your "hint" is not helping, I already thought about that.

Comment: So, what exactly are expecting in response to your question? If you are having specific problems then let people know so they don't waste time trying to assist with things you already know. You say you want to show $E$ is compact but you already have a counter example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The set $E$ is not bounded: for each $m\in\mathbb N$ and we can define 
$$
x=(1,\tfrac12,\tfrac13-\tfrac14,\tfrac14-\tfrac18,\ldots,\tfrac1m-\tfrac1{2^{m-1}},0,\ldots). 
$$
Then
$$
\|x\|_1=\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1k-\sum_{k=2}^{m-1}\frac1{2^k}\geq-1+\sum_{k=1}^m\frac1k.
$$
So there exist $x\in E$ with norm arbitrarily large. As $E\subset K$, $K$ is also unbounded and thus not compact.

- The set $E$ is not closed: consider the elements
  $$
  (1-\tfrac1m,0,0,\ldots).
  $$
  The limit is $(1,0,0,\ldots)$, which is not in $E$.
- The set $K$ is closed. A Cauchy sequence in $K$ is Cauchy in $\ell^1$, which is complete, so the limit exists. As norm convergence implies entrywise convergence, the entries of the limit satisfy the same inequalities as the entries int the Cauchy sequence.
- The set $E$ is not open. Let $x\in E$ be the element given by 
  $$
  x_n=\begin{cases}
  2^{-n}-4^{-n},&\ n=2^k\ \text{ for some } k\\[0.3cm] 0,&\ \text{ otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  Now, for each $m\in\mathbb N$, let $x^{(m)}\in \ell^1$ be the element given by 
  $$
  x^{(m)}_n=\begin{cases}
  x_n,&\ n=2^k,\ k\ne m\\[0.3cm] 2^{-m},&\ n=2^m\\[0.3cm] 0,&\ \text{ otherwise}
  \end{cases}
  $$
  Then $x^{(m)}\not\in E$ (because of the $2^m$ coordinate), but $\|x^{(m)}-x\|_1=4^{-m}\to0$